# GC overhead limit exceeded when building android source

Tags: java, android-source, android-build

```
****[ 35% 11837/33004] build out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v21_intermediates/classes.jack 

FAILED:/bin/bash -c 
"
(mkdir -p out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v21_intermediates/) 
&& (java -Xmx3500m -jar out/host/linux-x86/framework/jill.jar --output out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v21_intermediates/classes.jack.tmpjill.jack prebuilts/sdk/21/android.jar) 
&& (mkdir -p out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v21_intermediates/classes.jack.tmpjill.res) 
&& (unzip -qo prebuilts/sdk/21/android.jar -d out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v21_intermediates/classes.jack.tmpjill.res) 
&& (find out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v21_intermediates/classes.jack.tmpjill.res -iname \"*.class\" -delete) 
&& (JACK_VERSION=2.26.RELEASE out/host/linux-x86/bin/jack @build/core/jack-default.args --verbose error -D jack.import.resource.policy=keep-first -D jack.import.type.policy=keep-first --import out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v21_intermediates/classes.jack.tmpjill.jack --import-resource out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v21_intermediates/classes.jack.tmpjill.res --output-jack out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v21_intermediates/classes.jack) 
&& (rm -rf out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v21_intermediates/classes.jack.tmpjill.res) 
&& (rm out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v21_intermediates/classes.jack.tmpjill.jack)
"
GC overhead limit exceeded
Try increasing heap size with java option '-Xmx'
Warning: This may have produced partial or corrupted output.
[ 35% 11837/33004] Building with Jack: out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core-all_intermediates/with-local/classes.dex
FAILED: /bin/bash out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core-all_intermediates/with-local/classes.dex.rsp
Communication error with Jack server (52)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
build/core/ninja.mk:139: recipe for target 'ninja_wrapper' failed
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1****
```

This is the error message where the building process stopped, it says try to increase heap size with java option "-Xmx",but I do not know how to config it when building the android source.

Comment: How much memory does this machine have?

Comment: The machine's memory size is 4G , maybe it's not enough for this building.

Comment: The -Xmx3500m may not be respected.  I would see first if it completes on a machine with more memory.

Comment: Try this answer.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34940793/increasing-heap-size-while-building-the-android-source-code-on-ubuntu-15-10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34940793/increasing-heap-size-while-building-the-android-source-code-on-ubuntu-15-10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like a bug in Android makefiles - 3500 megabytes is really not enough to build some Java packages inside Android. It's hardcoded value, you can find it in [build/core/config.mk](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master/core/config.mk#555). For now you can simply increase it locally (however it's weird that it isn't placed in some environment variable).

I've increased it to 5500 megabytes and it works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for help , I found out the **-Xmx**  option in `config.mk`, but there are no more memories to be used, Maybe I should increase the machine's memory.

Comment: @yuiopt yeah, highly parallel build is quite memory-heavy - you can increase swap and/or decrease the number of build threads.

Comment: Hello, I run into this issue and I found this page from the docs : https://source.android.com/source/jack.html#jack_troubleshooting . Also, I do not found the xmx command in the config.mk file, only this line  : 

APICHECK_COMMAND := $(APICHECK) -JXmx1024m -J"classpath $(APICHECK_CLASSPATH)" 

Is this the line you are referring to ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35579646/android-source-code-compile-error-try-increasing-heap-size-with-java-option for more recent (in android 6.0) ways to fix this)

Comment: @icyerasor Thank you very mych,it is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Google recommends minimum 16GB of RAM for building source code and we have experienced that with Android N it is indeed mandatory.

Unless 16 GB of RAM is given to machine, reliability of source code build is really really low. You may try multiple configurations of jack-server and parameters but none of them may prove to be a reliable.

This is running thread of similar problems faced by many :-
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194027

I hope this helps !