# AOSP make build error

Tags: android, android-source, ninja

I'm trying to build aosp with make -jN on Mac OS, but it end with the next error :

```
  required: BlockingQueue<Runnable>
  found:    BlockingQueue
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
29 warnings
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1
```

at 43% of the process.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34940793/increasing-heap-size-while-building-the-android-source-code-on-ubuntu-15-10

Answer (score -1):

To get rid of the error you need to update the API.
    $ make update-api
Let it update and then start make again.
    $ make -jN