# Recipe for target 'ninja_wrapper' failed

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to compile android 7.0 from the AOSP but got the above error (cf title). The logs show several errors which seem to be about *Test.java files in the packages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/ folder

Below are some examples of error :

```
FAILED: /bin/bash -c "(rm -f out/target/common/obj/APPS/DialerTests_intermediates/jack.check.timestamp ) && (rm -f out/target/common/obj/APPS/DialerTests_intermediates/jack.check.timestamp.java-source-list $
ERROR:  AOSP/packages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/calllog/CallLogListItemHelperTest.java:26: The import com.android.contacts.common.CallUtil cannot be resolved
ERROR: AOSP/packages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/calllog/CallLogListItemHelperTest.java:27: The import com.android.dialer.PhoneCallDetails cannot be resolved
ERROR: AOSP/packages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/calllog/CallLogListItemHelperTest.java:28: The import com.android.dialer.R cannot be resolved
ERROR: AOSP/packages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/calllog/CallLogListItemHelperTest.java:30: The import com.android.dialer.util.AppCompatConstants cannot be resolved
ERROR: AOSP/packages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/calllog/CallLogListItemHelperTest.java:53: CallLogListItemHelper cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: AOSP/packages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/calllog/CallLogListItemHelperTest.java:56: CallLogListItemViewHolder cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: AOSP/packages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/calllog/CallLogListItemHelperTest.java:68: PhoneCallDetailsHelper cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: AOSP/packages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/calllog/CallLogListItemHelperTest.java:69: PhoneCallDetailsHelper cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: AOSP/packages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/calllog/CallLogListItemHelperTest.java:70: CallLogListItemHelper cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: AOSP/packages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/calllog/CallLogListItemHelperTest.java:70: CallLogListItemHelper cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: AOSP/packages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/calllog/CallLogListItemHelperTest.java:71: CallLogListItemViewHolder cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: AOSP/packages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/calllog/CallLogListItemHelperTest.java:71: CallLogListItemViewHolder cannot be resolved
ERROR: AOSP/packages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/calllog/CallLogListItemHelperTest.java:77: CallLogListItemHelper cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: AOSP/packages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/calllog/CallLogListItemHelperTest.java:78: CallLogListItemViewHolder cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: AOSP/packages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/calllog/CallLogListItemHelperTest.java:85: CallLogListItemViewHolder cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: AOSP/packages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/calllog/CallLogListItemHelperTest.java:106: CallLogListItemViewHolder cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: AOSP/packages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/calllog/CallLogListItemHelperTest.java:110: PhoneCallDetails cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: AOSP/packages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/calllog/CallLogListItemHelperTest.java:111: AppCompatConstants cannot be resolved to a variable
ERROR: AOSP/packages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/calllog/CallLogListItemHelperTest.java:112: CallLogListItemHelper cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: AOSP/packages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/calllog/CallLogListItemHelperTest.java:112: CallLogListItemViewHolder cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: AOSP/packages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/calllog/CallLogListItemHelperTest.java:113: CallLogListItemViewHolder cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: AOSP/packages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/calllog/CallLogListItemHelperTest.java:117: PhoneCallDetails cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: AOSP/packages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/calllog/CallLogListItemHelperTest.java:118: AppCompatConstants cannot be resolved to a variable
ERROR: AOSP/packages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/calllog/CallLogListItemHelperTest.java:119: CallLogListItemHelper cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: AOSP/packages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/calllog/CallLogListItemHelperTest.java:119: CallLogListItemViewHolder cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: AOSPpackages/apps/Dialer/tests/src/com/android/dialer/calllog/CallLogListItemHelperTest.java:120: CallLogListItemViewHolder cannot be resolved to a type
```

Does anybody have any idea to fix my problem please?

Thanks

Comment: What is the command you use to compile it?

Comment: source build/envsetup.sh 
lunch
make -j4
PS : as the documentation says

Comment: Try answer by Layne Zhang and Vignesh Prasad V found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34940793/increasing-heap-size-while-building-the-android-source-code-on-ubuntu-15-10)

Comment: Ok I will try it. Thks