# Out of memory with jack

Tags: android, out-of-memory, jack-compiler

I'm testing the new compilation chain to start using lambdas.

My `build.gradle` file contains:

```
android {
    ...
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24 rc3"

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app.id"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true

        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

I'm using Android Studio 2.1.1.

When I build the app the compilation takes ages and then ends with an Out of memory error:

> Execution failed for task
>   ':app:compileAppNameJavaWithJack'.
>
> > java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Sometimes the compilation just hangs when performing:

```
:app:compileMyAppNameDebugJavaWithJack
```

I found [in the troubleshooting section here](https://source.android.com/source/jack.html#the_jack_toolchain) a way to fix it but I can't find the `.jack` file with the configuration.
In [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194027) someone mentioned that the file could have been renamed to jack.settings but I can't find that file either.

Do you know where the file is? Do you know how to fix the Out of memory error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue setting:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M
```

in the `gradle.properties`file

Check [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html) for more info about the setting

Answer (score 0):

See also this question, which solved this problem for me:

[Android source code compile error: "Try increasing heap size with java option '-Xmx<size>'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35579646/android-source-code-compile-error-try-increasing-heap-size-with-java-option)

I find that jack's virtual size is around ~8G by the time my build is done.