# Error on compiling AOSP: make: [out/build-aosp_arm.ninja] Killed

Tags: android, makefile, compiler-errors, compilation, android-source

Trying to build android from aosp follow the android doc on ubuntu 16.04 x64,jdk and toolchain installed finished,but the build stopped after a few minutes.here is the build log:

```
e@ubuntu:/e/aosp$ make -j4
find: ‘vendor’: No such file or directory
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=7.0
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_arm
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.4.0-45-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=NYC
OUT_DIR=out
AUX_OS_VARIANT_LIST=
============================================
ninja: no work to do.
[1/1] soong_build out/soong/build.ninja
Running kati to generate build-aosp_arm.ninja...
out/build-aosp_arm.ninja is missing, regenerating...
find: ‘vendor’: No such file or directory
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=7.0
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_arm
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.4.0-45-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=NYC
OUT_DIR=out
AUX_OS_VARIANT_LIST=
============================================
including out/soong/Android-aosp_arm.mk ...
including ./art/Android.mk ...
including ./bionic/Android.mk ...
including ./bootable/recovery/Android.mk ...
including ./build/make/Android.mk ...
including ./build/target/board/Android.mk ...
including ./build/target/product/security/Android.mk ...
including ./build/tools/Android.mk ...
including ./cts/Android.mk ...
FindEmulator: find: `cts/apps/CtsVerifier/src/android': No such file or directory
FindEmulator: find: `cts/hostsidetests/os/test-apps/HostLinkVerificationApp/src': No such file or directory
FindEmulator: find: `cts/libs/commonutil/src': No such file or directory
FindEmulator: cd: cts/tests/libcore/ojluni/resources: No such file or directory
including ./dalvik/Android.mk ...
including ./developers/samples/android/security/FingerprintDialog/Application/src/main/Android.mk ...
including ./development/apps/BluetoothDebug/Android.mk ...
including ./development/apps/BuildWidget/Android.mk ...
...
including ./development/samples/Support7Demos/Android.mk ...
build/core/package_internal.mk:143: Empty argument supplied to find-subdir-assets
including ./development/samples/SupportAppNavigation/Android.mk ...
including ./development/samples/SupportDesignDemos/Android.mk ...
including ./development/samples/SupportLeanbackDemos/Android.mk ...
including ./development/samples/SupportLeanbackShowcase/app/src/main/Android.mk ...
including ./development/samples/SupportPercentDemos/Android.mk ...
...
including ./external/tlsdate/Android.mk ...
including ./external/toybox/Android.mk ...
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ,
including ./external/tpm2/Android.mk ...
including ./external/tremolo/Android.mk ...
...
including ./frameworks/av/tools/resampler_tools/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/base/Android.mk ...
build/core/package_internal.mk:143: Empty argument supplied to find-subdir-assets
including ./frameworks/compile/libbcc/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/compile/mclinker/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/compile/slang/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/data-binding/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/ex/camera2/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/ex/common/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/ex/framesequence/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/minikin/app/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/minikin/libs/minikin/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/minikin/sample/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/minikin/tests/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/ml/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/multidex/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/native/cmds/bugreportz/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/native/cmds/cmd/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/native/cmds/dumpstate/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/native/cmds/flatland/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/native/cmds/installd/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/native/cmds/ip-up-vpn/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/native/cmds/rawbu/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/native/opengl/libagl/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/native/opengl/libs/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/native/opengl/tests/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/native/services/inputflinger/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/native/services/nativeperms/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/native/services/sensorservice/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/native/services/surfaceflinger/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/native/vulkan/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/opt/bitmap/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/opt/bluetooth/Android.mk ...
FindEmulator: find: `frameworks/opt/bluetooth/src/android/bluetooth/client/pbap': No such file or directory
including ./frameworks/opt/calendar/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/opt/chips/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/opt/colorpicker/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/opt/datetimepicker/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/opt/inputmethodcommon/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/opt/net/ethernet/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/opt/net/ims/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/opt/net/voip/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/opt/net/wifi/libwifi_hal/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/opt/net/wifi/libwifi_system/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/opt/net/wifi/service/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/opt/net/wifi/tests/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/opt/photoviewer/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/opt/setupwizard/library/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/opt/setupwizard/navigationbar/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/opt/telephony/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/opt/timezonepicker/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/opt/vcard/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/rs/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/support/Android.mk ...
FindEmulator: find: `frameworks/support/design/dummy': No such file or directory
FindEmulator: find: `frameworks/support/v17/leanback/dummy': No such file or directory
FindEmulator: find: `frameworks/support/v17/preference-leanback/dummy': No such file or directory
including ./frameworks/volley/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/webview/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/wilhelm/src/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/wilhelm/tests/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/akm/AK8975_FS/akmdfs/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/akm/AK8975_FS/libsensors/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/broadcom/libbt/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/broadcom/wlan/bcmdhd/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/google/apf/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/intel/audio_media/hdmi/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/intel/bootstub/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/intel/common/libmix/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/intel/common/libstagefrighthw/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/intel/common/libva/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/intel/common/libwsbm/src/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/intel/common/omx-components/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/intel/common/utils/ISV/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/intel/common/utils/ituxd/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/intel/common/utils/media_resource_manager/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/intel/common/wrs_omxil_core/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/intel/img/hwcomposer/merrifield/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/intel/img/hwcomposer/moorefield_hdmi/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/intel/img/psb_headers/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/intel/img/psb_video/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/interfaces/bluetooth/1.0/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/interfaces/boot/1.0/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/interfaces/nfc/1.0/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/interfaces/radio/1.0/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/interfaces/tests/baz/1.0/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/interfaces/tests/expression/1.0/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/interfaces/tests/libhwbinder/1.0/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/interfaces/tests/libhwbinder/aidl/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/interfaces/wifi/1.0/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/interfaces/wifi/supplicant/1.0/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/invensense/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/libhardware/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/libhardware_legacy/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/marvell/bt/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/qcom/audio/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/qcom/bootctrl/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/qcom/bt/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/qcom/camera/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/qcom/display/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/qcom/gps/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/qcom/keymaster/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/qcom/media/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/qcom/power/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/qcom/wlan/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/ril/libril/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/ril/librilutils/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/ril/reference-ril/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/ril/rild/Android.mk ...
including ./libcore/Android.mk ...
including ./out/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/BasicSmsReceiver/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/Bluetooth/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/Browser2/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/Calculator/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/Calendar/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/Camera2/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/CarrierConfig/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/CellBroadcastReceiver/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/CertInstaller/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/Contacts/Android.mk ...
FindEmulator: find: `packages/apps/Contacts/src-N': No such file or directory
FindEmulator: find: `packages/apps/PhoneCommon/src-N': No such file or directory
including ./packages/apps/DeskClock/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/DevCamera/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/Dialer/Android.mk ...
FindEmulator: find: `packages/apps/Dialer/InCallUI/src-N': No such file or directory
FindEmulator: find: `packages/apps/PhoneCommon/src-N': No such file or directory
including ./packages/apps/Email/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/EmergencyInfo/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/ExactCalculator/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/Gallery/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/Gallery2/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/HTMLViewer/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/KeyChain/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/Launcher2/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/Launcher3/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/LegacyCamera/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/ManagedProvisioning/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/Messaging/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/Music/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/MusicFX/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/Nfc/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/OneTimeInitializer/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/PackageInstaller/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/PhoneCommon/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/Protips/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/Provision/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/QuickSearchBox/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/Settings/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/SoundRecorder/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/SpareParts/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/SpeechRecorder/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/Stk/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/TV/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/Tag/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/Terminal/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/Test/connectivity/sl4n/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/TvSettings/QuickSettings/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/TvSettings/Settings/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/apps/UnifiedEmail/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/experimental/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/inputmethods/OpenWnn/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/providers/BlockedNumberProvider/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/providers/BookmarkProvider/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/providers/CalendarProvider/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/providers/CallLogProvider/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/providers/ContactsProvider/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/providers/DownloadProvider/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/providers/MediaProvider/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/providers/PartnerBookmarksProvider/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/providers/TelephonyProvider/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/providers/TvProvider/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/providers/UserDictionaryProvider/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/screensavers/Basic/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/screensavers/PhotoTable/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/screensavers/WebView/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/services/Car/Android.mk ...
FindEmulator: find: `packages/services/Car/car-support-lib/dummy': No such file or directory
including ./packages/services/Mms/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/services/Telecomm/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/services/Telephony/Android.mk ...
including ./packages/wallpapers/LivePicker/Android.mk ...
including ./pdk/apps/HelloPDK/Android.mk ...
including ./pdk/apps/TestingCamera/Android.mk ...
including ./pdk/apps/TestingCamera2/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/libraries/annotations/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/libraries/app-helpers/Android.mk ...
FindEmulator: find: `platform_testing/libraries/app-helpers/src': No such file or directory
FindEmulator: find: `platform_testing/libraries/app-helpers/src': No such file or directory
including ./platform_testing/libraries/aupt-lib/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/libraries/base-app-helpers/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/libraries/chrome-app-helper/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/libraries/facebook-app-helper/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/libraries/flightdemo-app-helper/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/libraries/gmail-app-helper/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/libraries/google-app-camera-helper/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/libraries/google-docs-app-helper/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/libraries/google-keyboard-app-helper/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/libraries/google-messenger-app-helper/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/libraries/launcher-helper/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/libraries/maps-app-helper/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/libraries/photos-app-helper/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/libraries/play-books-app-helper/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/libraries/play-movies-app-helper/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/libraries/play-music-app-helper/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/libraries/play-store-app-helper/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/libraries/power-helper/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/libraries/recents-app-helper/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/libraries/reddit-app-helper/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/libraries/settings-app-helper/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/libraries/timeresult-helper/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/libraries/tunein-app-helper/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/libraries/youtube-app-helper/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/scripts/perf-setup/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/tests/androidbvt/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/tests/camera/aupt-profile/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/tests/functional/applinktests/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/tests/functional/appsmoke/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/tests/functional/downloadapp/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/tests/functional/externalstorage/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/tests/functional/launchertests/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/tests/functional/notificationtests/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/tests/functional/otatests/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/tests/functional/permission/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/tests/functional/settingstests/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/tests/functional/testapks/applinktestapp/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/tests/functional/testapks/permissiontestappmv1/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/tests/jank/UbSystemUiJankTests/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/tests/jank/androidtvjanktests/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/tests/jank/dialer/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/tests/jank/jankmicrobenchmark/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/tests/jank/sysapp/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/tests/jank/sysapp_wear/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/tests/jank/uibench/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/tests/jank/uibench_wear/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/tests/jank/webview/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/tests/perf/PerformanceAppTest/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/tests/perf/PerformanceLaunch/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/tests/perf/PowerPerfTest/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/tests/smokefast/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/utils/crashcollector/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/utils/dialogs/Android.mk ...
including ./platform_testing/utils/permissions/Android.mk ...
including ./prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.mk ...
including ./prebuilts/misc/Android.mk ...
build/core/ninja.mk:168: recipe for target 'out/build-aosp_arm.ninja' failed
make: *** [out/build-aosp_arm.ninja] Killed

#### make failed to build some targets (10:06 (mm:ss)) ####
```

and i have try the showcommands arg but it did't tell me any details.how can i get more verbose by the way?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you run all the previous commands before `make` such as:

```
$ source build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch aosp_arm-user
$ make -j4
```

See: [Preparing to Build](https://source.android.com/source/building) for more details.

If you did, most likely you run of the memory which would explain why the compilation process got killed:

> make: *** [out/build-aosp_arm.ninja] Killed

As I had similar problem when compiling on EC2 instance and I had this when running `dmesg`:

```
aosp$ sudo dmesg | tail
Out of memory: Kill process 3252 (ckati) score 903 or sacrifice child
Killed process 3252 (ckati) total-vm:982496kB, anon-rss:916824kB, file-rss:20kB
```

#### Solution

First of all, check the resource limits by: `ulimit -a` and increase max memory size if needed.

If your total system memory is low (`top -m`), for example when you're running this compilation on VM instance (like EC2), try increasing your memory and try again.

Another easier solution is to [add a swap file](https://askubuntu.com/a/796997/78223) to increase your total system memory.

If you've got another memory issue later on, consider [increasing heap size for java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35579646/55075) as well.

Answer (score 2):

May be not enough memory. Check your computer memory, At lease 8GB.

If you have only 8GB, build with make -j1 (you can build with make, when fails , use make -j1 instead, to continue build the left projects)

If you have 16GB, good luck , build with make or make -j4

one more thread, 4G more memory.