# jack-admin: command not found

Tags: android, android-source, android-build

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS to compile Android 7.1.1 on a VM inside windows with 11GB of RAM assigned. Android keeps failing to build due to "out of memory errors" as seen below.

```
Out of memory error (version 1.2-rc4 'Carnac'(298900f95d7bdecfceb327f9d201a1348397ed8a843843 by android-jack-team@google.com)).
GC overhead limit exceeded.
Try increasing heap size with java option '-Xmx<size>'.
Warning: This may have produced partial or corrupted output.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1
[0;31m#### make failed to build some targets (03:04:37 (hh:mm:ss)) ####
```

I am trying to follow this guide: [Android source code compile error: "Try increasing heap size with java option '-Xmx<size>'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35579646/android-source-code-compile-error-try-increasing-heap-size-with-java-option) to increase the heap size.

As the top answer suggests the jack server needs to be stopped and started using jack-admin.
When I use this command I am given the error message: "jack-admin: command cannot be found" how do I add jack-admin to the path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jack server can be found in the Android source code in the location of **prebuilts/sdk/tools** and can be run from there.

```
prebuilts/sdk/tools$ ./jack-admin stop-server
prebuilts/sdk/tools$ ./jack-admin start-server
```

Or this folder can then be added to the PATH by running:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/myandroid/prebuilts/sdk/tools
```